# TensorFlow Estimator save in web format (tfjs)

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorflow.js

I have a linar estimator in TF 2.2 and currently save it in following way

```
linear_est = tf.estimator.LinearClassifier(feature_columns=feature_columns)
...
serving_input_fn = tf.estimator.export.build_parsing_serving_input_receiver_fn(
tf.feature_column.make_parse_example_spec(feature_columns))
export_path = linear_est.export_saved_model(
              "./model/", serving_input_fn)
```

With this I get a .pb file and a variables folder, but I need to run the prediction in tfjs, because python tf 2.2 is too big for AWS Lambda.

Is there a possiblity to save it directly from python to web format?
I already tried to convert it with this tutorial
https://www.tensorflow.org/js/tutorials/conversion/import_saved_model
but it is not working. I'm also not sure what is --output_node_names

I created the model with Python 3.8 and now I'm using 3.6.8 in the venv for the converter, because converter is not running with 3.8

```
(venv) PS C:\predict\web> tensorflowjs_converter --input_format=tf_saved_model --saved_model_tags=serve sold/model/1588619275 sold_web
2020-05-06 22:17:35.434178: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2
WARNING:tensorflow:From c:\predict\web\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\ops\resource_variable_ops.py:1786: calling BaseResourceVariable.__init__ (from tensorflow.python.ops.resource_variable_ops) with constraint is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
If using Keras pass *_constraint arguments to layers.
WARNING:tensorflow:Issue encountered when serializing global_step.
Type is unsupported, or the types of the items don't match field type in CollectionDef. Note this is a warning and probably safe to ignore.
to_proto not supported in EAGER mode.
WARNING:tensorflow:Issue encountered when serializing variables.
Type is unsupported, or the types of the items don't match field type in CollectionDef. Note this is a warning and probably safe to ignore.
to_proto not supported in EAGER mode.
WARNING:tensorflow:Issue encountered when serializing trainable_variables.
Type is unsupported, or the types of the items don't match field type in CollectionDef. Note this is a warning and probably safe to ignore.
to_proto not supported in EAGER mode.
2020-05-06 22:17:36.264215: I tensorflow/core/grappler/devices.cc:60] Number of eligible GPUs (core count >= 8, compute capability >= 0.0): 0 (Note: TensorFlow was not compiled with CUDA support)
2020-05-06 22:17:36.283583: I tensorflow/core/grappler/clusters/single_machine.cc:356] Starting new session
2020-05-06 22:17:36.296771: E tensorflow/core/grappler/grappler_item_builder.cc:656] Init node linear/linear_model/linear/linear_model/linear/linear_model/category_id/category_id_lookup/hash_table/table_init/LookupTableImportV2 doesn't exist in graph
WARNING:tensorflow:From c:\predict\web\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflowjs\converters\tf_saved_model_conversion_v2.py:313: load (from tensorflow.python.saved_model.loader_impl) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
This function will only be available through the v1 compatibility library as tf.compat.v1.saved_model.loader.load or tf.compat.v1.saved_model.load. There will be a new function for importing SavedModels in Tensorflow 2.0.
WARNING:tensorflow:From c:\predict\web\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflowjs\converters\tf_saved_model_conversion_v2.py:315: convert_variables_to_constants (from tensorflow.python.framework.graph_util_impl) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use `tf.compat.v1.graph_util.convert_variables_to_constants`
WARNING:tensorflow:From c:\predict\web\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\graph_util_impl.py:277: extract_sub_graph (from tensorflow.python.framework.graph_util_impl) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use `tf.compat.v1.graph_util.extract_sub_graph`
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\nibur\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\users\nibur\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\predict\web\venv\Scripts\tensorflowjs_converter.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "c:\predict\web\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflowjs\converters\converter.py", line 671, in pip_main
    main([' '.join(sys.argv[1:])])
  File "c:\predict\web\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflowjs\converters\converter.py", line 675, in main
    convert(argv[0].split(' '))
  File "c:\predict\web\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflowjs\converters\converter.py", line 618, in convert
    weight_shard_size_bytes=weight_shard_size_bytes)
  File "c:\predict\web\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflowjs\converters\tf_saved_model_conversion_v2.py", line 462, in convert_tf_saved_model
    weight_shard_size_bytes=weight_shard_size_bytes)
  File "c:\predict\web\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflowjs\converters\tf_saved_model_conversion_v2.py", line 142, in optimize_graph
    ', '.join(unsupported))
ValueError: Unsupported Ops in the model before optimization
SparseFillEmptyRows, Unique, LookupTableFindV2, ParseExampleV2, HashTableV2, SparseSegmentSum, AsString, SparseReshape
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So it seems you are using ops that are not supported in the browser implementation of TensorFlow.js (this does not apply to Node.js which can execute savedModels without conversion).

TensorFlow.js supports a few hundred or so ops from the original TensorFlow implementation for the browser based implementation, so the only way for this to run in the browser right now is to:

1. Implement the ops in JS - contribute to the open source code on
   Github for the ops that are missing.
2. Change the ops you are using to use supported ops.

You can see the supported ops here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-converter/blob/master/tfjs-converter/docs/supported_ops.md